# Silverlight sample applications

Tags: silverlight, sample

I'm developing small silverlight apps since a few months and now I'm looking for some resources to improve my apps. I read through quite a bunch of samples and I know the basic technologies, now I'm looking for a complete, robust Silverlight application that I could study to learn the best SL app design approaches. I'm not looking for small code chunks but for a complete App with a proper design. Something that shows how it call comes together, where to put the logic, how to handle events and link UI components together, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Microsoft Health Common User Interface](http://www.mscui.net/) group has some pretty neat and complex Silverlight demonstrators.  There are not fully fledged functional apps from a data perspective, but show a lot of the UI concepts in far more depth than a simple tutorial.